# Trim Particular String

Tags: c#, string, split

I have a string like this:
**"Instructions: Hello : How are you"**

And i want result string like this **"Hello : How are you"**

In string after **"Instructions:"** I can add as many as sentences starting with **colon ":"** like i start **: How are you**

code i am using

```
  string[] MyString = oldstring.Split(':');
  if (MyString != null && MyString .Length > 1)
  {
       oldstring = MyString[1].Replace(";", "").TrimStart();
  }
```

My code **trims "Instructions:"** and all other sentences after **second colon ":"** i.e **after Hello**

I want such only  **"Instructions:"** word will be trimmed and return whole string regardless of number of sentences and colon it contains.

Please Suggest Logic and problem is that I **can use only Trim() Function**

**i am using C# and ASP.NET for language reference.**

Comment: It is not even clear what your desired result is.

Comment: Will "Instructions:" always be consistent? If so, use Left(string,numberofCharacters)

Comment: Maybe: `oldstring.StartsWith("Instructions:") ? oldstring.Substring(13).Trim() : oldstring;`... Result: `Hello : How are you`

Comment: dos instructions  can be repeated

Comment: Instructions can be altered to any word that is the problem i can not remove particular word or characters from start. also If any other sentence contains instructions word it will also be removed

Comment: can you post an exhaustive example please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How does the following not do what you want? (The question is vague to me).

```
string[] MyString = oldstring.Split(':');
if (MyString != null && MyString.Length > 1)
{
    MyString[0] = MyString[0].Trim();
}
oldstring = string.Join(":",MyString);
```

This will split oldstring into an array, trim the first word, then join the array together into a string again. The first word is trimmed, nothing else is touched.

After reading your question again, I'm starting to think that you're confusing what "Trim" means in this case. Trimming means removing whitespace. It looks like you're talking about removing the first word. If that's the case, change `MyString[0] = MyString[0].Trim();` to `MyString[0] = "";` and run the rest of the code as shown. This will remove the first word of the array and return the rest as a string.

Comment: please check again i had made few changes in question for better clarification

Comment: Thanks It works but a problem it gives string like this ": Hello : How are you" I want such that first colon ":" and space also be removed any way i will use remove() for that thanks again

Comment: @user3049290 That's easily solved by doing a `foreach` over the strings in the array and applying `.TrimStart()` to all of them.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for different commands relevant to particular words.

```
        if (oldstring.IndexOf(':') > -1)
        {
            oldstring = oldstring.Substring(oldstring.IndexOf(':') + 1).Trim();
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

This is done using Trim only.

```
string oldstring = "Instructions:Hello : How are you";
oldstring = oldstring.TrimStart("Instructions: ".ToArray());
```

Based on your requirement you to ToUpper() or ToLower().

Comment: This will only remove "Instructions:", he specifically said there are many different commands so he can't use particular words.

Comment: oldstring=oldstring.Substring(oldstring.IndexOf(':')+1).Trim();

Comment: His question is bit confusing anyways i had added one more answer .

Comment: sorry for bad presentation you can alter it actually i am bad at english